# Copying 1 column from multiple sheets into one sheet in the same workbook and them copy/paste a 2nd column from the same final sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am relative novice in VBA and my goal is to automatically copy one column (B) from 3 named sheets (source sheets) and paste them in a new sheet and them repeat the process for column C and so on until a defined column (see image for my goal, in this case I wanted until column D of the source sheets). The structure of all sheets is identical. Columns consist of numeric values.

I have tried to write a code (see below) however I am getting run-time error 1004 for the commented line. Also, not sure if the code will do what I want to. What am I doing wrong and any tips to improve it?

```
Sub CopyColumns3()

Dim sheetNames As Variant
sheetNames = Array("temp_column", "normalized_column", "derivative_column")

Dim columnLetters As Variant
columnLetters = Array("B", "C", "D")

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

' Create a new sheet after the last sheet in the workbook
sheets.Add After:=sheets(sheets.Count)

' Set the name of the new sheet
sheets(sheets.Count).Name = "A_final"

For i = 0 To UBound(sheetNames)
    For j = 0 To UBound(columnLetters)
        sheets(sheetNames(i)).columns(columnLetters(j)).Copy

        ' Check if there are any empty columns in the Destination sheet
        If sheets("A_final").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column = 256 Then
            ' If there are no empty columns, add a new column to the end of the sheet
            sheets("A_final").columns(sheets("A_final").columns.Count).EntireColumn.Insert
        End If

        sheets("A_final").Select
        ' The next line causes the problem
        sheets("A_final").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj3L7.png)

Comment: I've edited your post to remove the **bold** (it doesn't work in a code block) and instead uses a comment above it to indicate which line causes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Columns

```vb
Sub ColumnsToNewSheet()

    ' Define constants.
    
    Const DST_NAME As String = "A_final"
    Const DST_FIRST_COLUMN As String = "A"
    
    Dim sNames(): sNames = Array( _
        "temp_column", "normalized_column", "derivative_column")
    Dim sColumns(): sColumns = Array("B", "C", "D")

    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Add a new sheet, rename it and reference the first Destination column.
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Set dws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    dws.Name = DST_NAME
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Columns(DST_FIRST_COLUMN)
    
    ' Copy the Source columns to the Destination columns.
    ' This does sh1-col1,sh2-col1,sh3-col3... as requested.
    ' If you need sh1-col1,sh1-col2,sh1-col3... switch the loops.
    
    Dim srg As Range, sName, sColumn
    
    For Each sColumn In sColumns
        For Each sName In sNames
            Set srg = wb.Sheets(sName).Columns(sColumn)
            srg.Copy drg
            Set drg = drg.Offset(, 1) ' next Destination column
        Next sName
    Next sColumn

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Columns exported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest using `ForEach sc in srcColumns` and `ForEach sn in srcNames`. I also think you inverted the order of the loops.

Comment: Thanks so much!! It worked. I was really struggling with this part of the code (There were several steps until reaching this part). I believe I was complicating it.

Comment: @Emilio Silva: A rule of thumb is to use the *For Each...Next* loop for objects. Arrays aren't objects. If you carefully look at the posted screenshot, it 'clearly' shows that this is the order of the loops except for the wrong repeating `B` or `C` column from the *normalized_column* worksheet. Pay attention to the colors.

Comment: @VBasic2008 "use the For Each...Next loop for objects". Well, I use `For Each` for *iterables*, and `Array`s are iterables. If you prefer to iterate over indexes and spend more characters indexing over the matrix, it's your choice. "look at the posted screenshot". Sorry, I looked at the posted code.

Comment: From the VBA documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement: "Repeats a group of statements for each element in an array or collection."

Comment: @VBasic2008 If I wanted to do this for all the columns in each source sheet (they have the same structure and number of columns and rows). I tried can srcColumns = VBA.Array("B:CS") but it only copies A1 from the 3 sheets and them all from 3rd sheet.  What you think is the problem? Must I define each column in the array can I use a range of columns?

Comment: You will have to write out all of the columns to use this code. It will be certainly easier than rewriting the whole code inviting new complications. Regarding efficiency, if you're satisfied with copying just values, you should consider using arrays. Consider asking another question describing your issue and see what comes up.

Comment: @Emilio Silva: You made a valid point and gave me something to think about (reconsider). It's just a couple of elements so efficiency isn't an issue. If I don't declare the Control variables `As Variant` I'll write 60 fewer characters: 7 on each *For* line, 8 on each variable declaration, 4 for each `VBA.` used to ensure a zero-based array, and 22 in the loop. That's quite a lot. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why should you have that check for column 256.

However, when it is triggered, you call `Range.Insert`, which clears the `CutCopyMode`. Therefore, `Range.PasteSpecial` fails because there is nothing to paste.

You can move the check before the `Range.Copy` call, or get rid of it altogether.